# Plot time series and work out number of times a threshold is exceeded

Tags: r, plot, time-series

I have a csv with a 15 minute interval time series of data covering several years. Example data format:

```
    Time stamp  Value
07/07/2003 08:00    10
07/07/2003 08:15    10
07/07/2003 08:30    10.5
07/07/2003 08:45    11
07/07/2003 09:00    13
07/07/2003 09:15    15
07/07/2003 09:30    14.5
07/07/2003 09:45    14
07/07/2003 10:00    10
07/07/2003 10:15    9
07/07/2003 10:30    8
07/07/2003 10:45    11
07/07/2003 11:00    12
07/07/2003 11:15    15
07/07/2003 11:30    13
07/07/2003 11:45    12
07/07/2003 12:00    10
```

I would like to read this into r studio and plot a time series with time stamp on the x axis and value on y.

The second part of the question is working out the number of times the value exceeds a certain threshold and then drops back below that threshold. For example it is => 12 a total of 8 times in the example data, occurring in 2 separate instances or groups within the time series. I am interested in the number of times the threshold is exceeded but key is calculating the number of times the time series is above a threshold in groupings such as described.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. Please provide a [reproducible example in r](//stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). The link I provided, will tell you how. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and review [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and then edit the question accordingly. You need to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us some efforts. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to plot the data. You need to transform Time_stamp to a date/time object using `as.POSIXct`:

```
df <- read.table(text="    Time_stamp  Value
'07/07/2003 08:00'    10
'07/07/2003 08:15'    10
'07/07/2003 08:30'    10.5
'07/07/2003 08:45'    11
'07/07/2003 09:00'    13
'07/07/2003 09:15'    15
'07/07/2003 09:30'    14.5
'07/07/2003 09:45'    14
'07/07/2003 10:00'    10
'07/07/2003 10:15'    9
'07/07/2003 10:30'    8
'07/07/2003 10:45'    11
'07/07/2003 11:00'    12
'07/07/2003 11:15'    15
'07/07/2003 11:30'    13
'07/07/2003 11:45'    12
'07/07/2003 12:00'    10", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df$Time_stamp <- as.POSIXct(df$Time_stamp, format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Time_stamp, y=Value))+
  geom_line()
```

[image]

And here's how to get the sequence above and equal to 12. I'm using `dplyr` and `rleid` from `data.table`

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
df%>%
  mutate(above=ifelse(df$Value<12, NA,(rleid(df$Value>=12))))%>%
  na.omit()%>%
  mutate(above=rleid(above))

           Time_stamp Value above
1 2003-07-07 09:00:00  13.0     1
2 2003-07-07 09:15:00  15.0     1
3 2003-07-07 09:30:00  14.5     1
4 2003-07-07 09:45:00  14.0     1
5 2003-07-07 11:00:00  12.0     2
6 2003-07-07 11:15:00  15.0     2
7 2003-07-07 11:30:00  13.0     2
8 2003-07-07 11:45:00  12.0     2
```

Comment: Many thanks Pierre this worked brilliantly with a minor amendment to read my data in from a csv.